# Reading file data without writing it to memory

Tags: c, file-io

I'm writing a C code and, for some reason, the code I'm writing just needs to read without actually writing to a memory buffer. I can conveniently write data to a dummy local variable, but there must be unnecessary overheads caused by writing some variables to memory.

```
int rdsize = 0;
while (rdsize > SOME_BYTES) {
  rdsize += fread (/* SOME BUFFER */, 1, SOME_BYTES - rdsize, file);
  if (rdsize == -1) break;
}
```

In a word, I'd like to make the above code work without /* SOME BUFFER */. How can I do this? Close solutions are also greatly welcomed.

Comment: You can use `fscanf` and discard what you have read .

Comment: The actual reason for that would help. Just discarding the data read is unusual and senseless, IMO. But maybe your use case is an exception.

Comment: If you aren't going to pull it into memory, why read from the media at all? It's a useless operation. Just don't bother reading, if you don't want the data. If you're trying to get a side-effect of a read, tell us what you want to happen, and we can perhaps help you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. Or in other words: what is your _actual_ problem?

Comment: Well I think I was just stupid. The code originally reads file data and is supposed to forward it to a library. The thing I wanted to achieve was the library's state variable, but I should have forwarded data to the library at the first place, which makes the read operation necessary. Sorry for void question :(

Comment: If a file is read in a forest and there's no buffer to receive it, has any I/O actually been performed?

Comment: i think you are confused by the meaning of memory buffer. it is almost impossible to do any thing without using memory, all happen in memory (processor registers are also kind of fast memory)

Comment: `if (rdsize == -1) break;` this is buggy, because of  this `rdsize += fread (..)`  . So when `fread` returns `-1` `rdsize` could be at a very big value already

Comment: also this one `rdsize > SOME_BYTES` i guess it should be `rdsize < SOME_BYTES`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fseek` to skip an arbitrary number of bytes:

```
#include<stdio.h>

// Inside a function:
success = fseek(file, 1, SOME_BYTES - rdsize, SEEK_CUR);
```

Comment: If the operation really needs to just 'skip' a portion of bytes, then your question would be just right solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if the purpose of your function is just  to know the size of the file then you can use this function:

```
int filesize(FILE *file ){
    int pos, size = -1;
    pos = fseek( file, 0, SEEK_CUR);         //save current position
    if( pos != -1 ){
              fseek(file, 0  , SEEK_END);    // move to end
       size = ftell(file);                   // get file size
              fseek(file, pos, SEEK_SET);    // rewind
    }
    return size;
}
```